# Angular 7 Dependency Inject HttpClient into Typescript export function

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection

Hi my angular prowess isn't so good for what I am trying to achieve.

I have an `export function` which fetches data from DB:

```
export async function BoardData(httpClient: HttpClient) {
  ...
  return result;
}
```

How would you dependency inject HttpClient into that?

I don't want to use `Injector` because that would require me to wrap my http request into `setTimeout()`, which doesn't work well inside and an `Observable.subscribe()`.

I've read about module providers, particularly about `useFactory` parameter, but I couldn't make it work. Please help.

**P.S. There are few similar sort of questions on Stack BUT neither of them address the QUESTION in due quality.**

This function is then called from inside of an export const as shown below:

```
export const initialState: BoardState = {
  board: BoardData(http),
  draggingBoard: null,
  cardInFlight: null,
  listInFlight: null,
  nextId: 1000,
  spilledCard: false,
  isCopying: false,
  shouldCopy: false
};
```

Comment: where are you using that function? if you use it in any form of class instance that is resolved through angular (eg components or services), you could simply inject the HttpClient into that object and then pass it to the function

Comment: it doesn't work inside a class, it is used inside a Store reducer of Skyhook's Kanban drag-n-drop. In other words it is called from inside an export const

Answer (score 0):

in my case I'am just passing httpClient as param to the exported function,
for exemple

```
getData(){
    .....
return exportedFunctionToGetData(this.httpClient);}
```

and in the header of the exported function :

```
exportedFunctionToGetData(httpClient : httpClient){...}
```

dont forget to import httpClient in the exported Function ts file:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score -2):

HttpClient is a service that is by default provided by `HttpClientModule`.

import this in your AppModule

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http'
....

@NgModule....
imports: [
   HttpClientModule
]
class AppModule {
}
```

Comment: simply importing a module doesn't autowire it with an export function